# Python group values in 2d list from CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, grouping, ordereddict

I have the following CSV

```
BBCP1,Grey,2140,805EC0FFFFE2,0000000066
BBCP1,Test,2150,805EC0FFFFE2,0000000066
BBCP1,Test,2151,805EC0FFFFE1,0000000066
BBCP1,Centre,2141,805EC0FFFFE3,000000077
BBCP1,Yellow,2142,805EC0FFFFE3,000000077
BBCP1,Purple,2143,805EC0FFFFE3,000000077
BBCP1,Green,2144,805EC0FFFFE3,000000077
BBCP1,Pink,2145,805EC0FFFFE3,000000077
```

I'm reading this data in using

```
data = list(csv.reader(open(csvFile)))
```

I want to turn this data into a 2d array or equivilent and **group by the value in the 4th column** (the MAC address), **preserving the order** they were in in the original list. So it would look like

```
[(BBCP1,Grey,2140,805EC0FFFFE2,0000000066),(BBCP1,Test,2150,805EC0FFFFE2,0000000066)],
[(BBCP1,Test,2151,805EC0FFFFE1,0000000066)],
[(BBCP1,Centre,2141,805EC0FFFFE3,000000077),
(BBCP1,Yellow,2142,805EC0FFFFE3,000000077),
(BBCP1,Purple,2143,805EC0FFFFE3,000000077),
(BBCP1,Green,2144,805EC0FFFFE3,000000077),
(BBCP1,Pink,2145,805EC0FFFFE3,000000077)]
```

Hopefully i've displayed the array correctly and it makes sense.

I then need to loop the arrays to output the data to file. Which i'm pretty sure i'm ok with a nested for loop.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `defaultdict` to group the data (`groupby` would require sorting and would be unefficient / would kill the order), then print the sorted dictionary values (sorting isn't really necessary, it's just to stabilize the output):

```
import csv,collections

d = collections.defaultdict(list)

for row in csv.reader(txt):
    mac_address = row[3]
    d[mac_address].append(row)

print(sorted(d.values()))
```

resulting in:

```
[[['BBCP1', 'Centre', '2141', '805EC0FFFFE3', '000000077'],
  ['BBCP1', 'Yellow', '2142', '805EC0FFFFE3', '000000077'],
  ['BBCP1', 'Purple', '2143', '805EC0FFFFE3', '000000077'],
  ['BBCP1', 'Green', '2144', '805EC0FFFFE3', '000000077'],
  ['BBCP1', 'Pink', '2145', '805EC0FFFFE3', '000000077']],
 [['BBCP1', 'Grey', '2140', '805EC0FFFFE2', '0000000066'],
  ['BBCP1', 'Test', '2150', '805EC0FFFFE2', '0000000066']],
 [['BBCP1', 'Test', '2151', '805EC0FFFFE1', '0000000066']]]
```

sorting according to key (the mac address):

```
values = [v for _,v in sorted(d.items())]
```

yields:

```
[[['BBCP1', 'Test', '2151', '805EC0FFFFE1', '0000000066']],
 [['BBCP1', 'Grey', '2140', '805EC0FFFFE2', '0000000066'],
  ['BBCP1', 'Test', '2150', '805EC0FFFFE2', '0000000066']],
 [['BBCP1', 'Centre', '2141', '805EC0FFFFE3', '000000077'],
  ['BBCP1', 'Yellow', '2142', '805EC0FFFFE3', '000000077'],
  ['BBCP1', 'Purple', '2143', '805EC0FFFFE3', '000000077'],
  ['BBCP1', 'Green', '2144', '805EC0FFFFE3', '000000077'],
  ['BBCP1', 'Pink', '2145', '805EC0FFFFE3', '000000077']]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i've tested your solution and it seems to work well :)

Answer (score 1):

hi i used `pandas` and  `groupby` to solve the problem. Hope this helps!!

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', header=None)
data.columns = ['A','B','C','D','E'] # random names to the column

def check(data):
    data_item = []
    for index,item in data.iterrows():
        data_item.append(item.tolist()))
    return data_item   

grouped_data = data.groupby('D',sort=False).apply(check)

for data in grouped_data:
    print(data)
```

Output #preserving the order

```
[['BBCP1', 'Grey', 2140, '805EC0FFFFE2', 66], ['BBCP1', 'Test', 2150, '805EC0FFFFE2', 66]]
[['BBCP1', 'Test', 2151, '805EC0FFFFE1', 66]]
[['BBCP1', 'Centre', 2141, '805EC0FFFFE3', 77], ['BBCP1', 'Yellow', 2142, '805EC0FFFFE3', 77], ['BBCP1', 'Purple', 2143, '805EC0FFFFE3', 77], ['BBCP1', 'Green', 2144, '805EC0FFFFE3', 77], ['BBCP1', 'Pink', 2145, '805EC0FFFFE3', 77]]
```